# Power Automate Flow - Prevent Line Breaks From SharePoint Multi Line Text Column in Flow Email

Tags: power-automate

Is there a way to stop a flow emailv2 from adding a line break when I bring in the string value of a SharePoint multi line column? It keeps adding a line break on top and below the text, which is making the email format look weird.

For example below, I want the **Please help me reset my password** to be in the same line with the **Request Description** text.

[image: Picture of Email Message Body]

*Current Email Output*

This is an automatic email notification

**Request Description:**

Please help me reset my password

**Completed by:** John Doe

---

*Desired Email Output*

This is an automatic email notification

**Request Description:** Please help me reset my password

**Completed by:** John Doe

Comment: is the multiline field rich text or plain?

Comment: It's plain text

Comment: Edit your question and provide screenshots and more details about how you are constructing the email message body.

Comment: I edited and added a screenshot. Trying to get the "Please help me reset my password" text to be in 1 line with the 'Request Description' text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Compose action to stitch together the bold text and the SharePoint plain text multiline field.

Then use the Output from the Compose action in the email body.

Here is the scenario in my test:

Flow definition:

[image]

the HTML view of the email:

[image]

Email arriving in Outlook:

[image]

You could also compose the whole HTML for the email body in one fell swoop in the compose action and just throw that into the email body.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, I really appreciate your answer and I'll definitely test it tomorrow morning, it's 11 pm here :), at work and mark it as the answer afterwards, thank you!!